# Codeigniter 3.0 phpunit testing not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I tried to add phpunit testing code to my already built up site using http://blog.a-way-out.net/blog/2015/06/12/codeigniter3-phpunit/
but its throw error:

```
1) Homemodel_test::test_When_you_get_all_news_Then_you_get_one_item
LogicException: CodeIgniter instance is not instantiated yet. You can't use `$th
is->simple_cache` at the moment. Please fix your test code.
E:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\tests\_ci_phpunit_test\CIPHPUnitTestNull
CodeIgniter.php:18
E:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\helpers\language_helper.php:10
E:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\core\ROCKERS_Controller.php:51
E:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\Home.php:51
E:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\tests\_ci_phpunit_test\CIPHPUnitTestRequ
est.php:292
E:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\tests\_ci_phpunit_test\CIPHPUnitTestRequ
est.php:215
E:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\tests\_ci_phpunit_test\CIPHPUnitTestRequ
est.php:126
E:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\tests\_ci_phpunit_test\CIPHPUnitTestCase
.php:106
E:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\tests\models\home_model_test.php:25
FAILURES!
```

Comment: config/autoload.php form where simple cache library is loaded
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','simple_cache','fb_connect','user_agent','template');

language_helper.php where its show error
$CI =& get_instance();
    //$CI->config->load('language');
    if (!$CI->simple_cache->is_cached('supported_languages')) {

Comment: add your comment in the question and add your Homemodel_test code too

Comment: As the error message says, "CodeIgniter instance is not instantiated yet. You can't use `$this->simple_cache` at the moment. Please fix your test code."

Comment: It means your test code is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your update ,this test file code.

<?php
class Homemodel_test extends TestCase
{
 
 public function test_When_you_get_all_news_Then_you_get_one_item()
 {
  $output = $this->request('GET', ['Home', 'index']);
  $this->assertContains('Real Estate :', $output);
 }
}

Comment: Is that all? I don't know why you get the error. To solve the problem, I need sample code to reproduce the error.

Comment: It seems the cause is in the `CodeIgniter\application\core\ROCKERS_Controller.php`.

Comment: require_once(APPPATH . 'helpers/language_helper' . EXT);
require_once(APPPATH . 'helpers/custom_helper' . EXT);
require_once(APPPATH . 'helpers/setting_helper' . EXT);

class ROCKERS_Controller extends MX_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        // get the CI superobject

        $CI = &get_instance();
        parent::__construct();
 
        /***** language *****/
    }

    public static function &get_instance()
    {
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

Comment: I think when you call `$CI = &get_instance();`, there is no CodeIgniter object yet. And the code you put here is difficult to read. I don't see here any more. If you need help, please post on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc.

ci-phpunit-test does not support HMVC now.
See https://github.com/kenjis/ci-phpunit-test/issues/34 to check the latest status.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue also, but in a bit different scenario. I noticed that context is "lost" after calling $this->request()

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('Random_model');
$CI->Random_model->save($data);

$output = $this->request('POST', 'https://example.com/random', $data);

// Now if I want to load model I need to call get_instance() again
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('Other_model');
```

If I do not call get_instance() again. I will get error:

> [phpunit] LogicException: CodeIgniter instance is not instantiated
>   yet. You can't use `$this->load` at the moment. Please fix your test
>   code.

Comment: How did you solve that? Can you remember? I am working on an old project and get the same issue!